# Could the T-1000 become a Tyrannosaurus balloon?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

It is established that the T-1000 from *Terminator 2: Judgment Day* can [change shape and alter its density in some form](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68889/why-doesnt-the-t-1000-retain-the-shape-of-the-slain-security-guard):

> The T-1000 walked forward. Because of the man’s obesity, it had been stressing its ability to expand molecularly by remaining in the Lewis form, so it had defaulted back to the more energy-efficient Officer Austin. It reached the bars. But it did not stop.

But could it become "hollow" and make it self much bigger? So big in fact that it could become a giant hollow T-Rex?

Comment: It'd be [like a lead balloon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZSkM-QEeUg).

Answer (score 22):

The short answer to this one is yes but also no and probably.

As to **absolute size**, it's clear that maintaining a form that's only a few percentage points larger than its base form is sufficiently taxing on the T-1000's power source as to encourage it to return to normal after just a few minutes. It follows that trying to become something as massive as a T-Rex could possibly overtax its batteries to the point of exhaustion. Since the power requirement is described as the major stumbling block, it's not difficult to imagine that with access to a ready power source that this limitation could be overcome.

The bigger problem is that the T-1000 can only mimic things that it has **physically sampled**. In the absence of a live Tyrannosaur, the best that it could do would be to mimic an immobile museum dinosaur.

> “I need a minute here, okay? You’re telling me it can imitate anything
>   it touches?”
>
> “**Anything it samples by physical contact**,” was the toneless reply.

Theoretically, however, it could build a second time-machine, travel back to the time of the dinosaurs (along with enough parts to build a third time machine) to sample a T-rex. It could then use the time machine parts to construct a third time machine and return to the year 1997.

Comment: So... elephant?

Comment: @legostormtrooper - Yes, almost certainly :-)

Comment: Did it ever impersonate a non-human? I don't remember the film well enough to be sure but it's conceivable it would be limited to sampling humans. Additionally consider the time it disguised itself as a floor. It needs to sample humans to become a perfect copy but maybe it can create "generic" shapes more easily.

Comment: @TimB It becomes a checkered floor at one point. http://stream1.gifsoup.com/view5/4704906/t1000-floor-o.gif

Comment: It is established that you can't bring parts with you to build a time machine.   Nothing mechanical, nothing electrical, no weapons.

Comment: @Thepopmachine - you can bring whatever you want, as long as it's enclosed by living tissue. Presumably the t-1000 could surround the pieces.

Comment: If only it had waited a couple more years, Jurassic Park would be out and it could just visit a cinema with plenty of T-rex balloo's...

Comment: @TimB: And it "sampled" the floor...by walking on it.

Comment: Technically the T-1000 could use one time machine to go back to the age of dinosaurs and then find different places to hide out until modern times. </ducks> .. I guess he might need two depending on when it became obsessed with Dinosaurs.

Comment: @MarkRogers - It's certainly not canon but the idea that any machine, no matter how sophisticated could last 100+ million years without suffering any sort of accident/incident seem vanishingly small. You'd basically want to park yourself under a mile of rock on the moon.

Comment: @Richard - lol true, though the T-1000 could technically be self-maintaining and so on and so forth.  Though who knows if even if a self-maintaining system T-1000 could last that long.

Comment: The T-1000 could also build a series of machines that would then build itself later, ok I should just be quiet.

Comment: Time travel requires exponential energy the farther you bend spacetime.

Comment: @ceesTimmerman - Is this based on the film's or is this just your personal opinion?

Comment: @Richard That was my physical reason for sending later Terminators back later (before considering [the logical one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/14425/5789)), bolstered by [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/4781/5789) which turned out to be speculation. AFAIK, only the size and fleshy field are canon limits for Skynet's time machine.

Comment: @Richard [Myron Stark](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Myron_Stark) being sent to 1920 instead of 2010 seems to disprove the energy argument.